# UNIX Command within Python Script receiving an error. Script executes command does not

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, call

I have a python script. On top of the script "from subprocess import call". If I write "call(["whoami"])" in the script and I execute the Python script from the unix command line it works, my username returns. But if I run a proprietary command with arguments, `"call(["mi_xx", "-s", "20141215","-e","20150121","-p",'TX%_XX%',"-f","test","-i","-x","-d"])"`

I get the error below. I run the same command directly in unix and it works. I have searched up and down. The python environment in unix is fine.

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Mixx.py", line 44, in <module>
    call(["mi_xx", "-s", "20141215","-e","20150121","-p",'TX%_XX%',"-f","test","-i","-x","-d"])
  File "/bb/util/common/ActivePythonEE_2.6.2_32bit/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 444, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/bb/util/common/ActivePythonEE_2.6.2_32bit/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/bb/util/common/ActivePythonEE_2.6.2_32bit/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1092, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
```

Comment: Have you tried supplying a full path to the file? The current working directory of the script may be different than the current working directory when run from the command line.

Comment: not sure if i did it correctly, I put the path in front.  call(["home/test/","mi_xx", "-s", "20141215","-e","20150121","-p",'TX%_XX%',"-f","test","-i","-x","-d"])  but  then i get a OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied.

Comment: Don't separate `/home/test/` from `mi_xx`. Make the first item `"/home/test/mi_xx"` if that is the path to the `mi_xx` executable. And if `test` is a file, try replacing it with an absolute path.

Comment: call(["home/test/mi_xx", "-s", "20141215","-e","20150121","-p",'TX%_XX%',"-f","test","-i","-x","-d"])   test is a directory.  So I did it this way still get Permission denied.

Comment: So, must ask stupid question: are you running the script as a different user than when your run the command from the command line?

Comment: nope its the same user

Comment: Do you get a different error (or no error!?) if you change `home/test/mi_xx` to `/home/test/mi_xx`? (Note the leading forward slash.)

Comment: Same error with / or no slash in the front

Comment: "No such file or directory" is solved (by providing the full path). [edit] your question and include the permission error. If `mi_xx` is a script then make sure that it has a valid shebang (`#!...`) and executable permissions (`chmod +x`).